# jhipster docker-compose: *TypeError: Cannot read property 'generator-jhipster' of undefined*

Tags: docker-compose, jhipster

When I try to execute jhipster docker-compose it comes to an error and I don't know what am I doing wrong.

1. I create a jhipster Microservice Gateway App with JHipster generators

   > generator-jhipster-module-2.2.0 and generator-jhipster-docker-2.2.0
2. I create a jhipster Microservice App with JHipster generators

   > generator-jhipster-module-2.2.0 and generator-jhipster-docker-2.2.0
3. I followed the construction at http://www.jhipster.tech/docker-compose/

I answered the upcoming questions as followed:

1. Which *type* of application would you like to deploy?

   > Microservice application
2. Which *type* of gateway would you like to use?

   > JHipster gateway based on Netflix Zuul
3. Enter the root directory where your gateway(s) and microservices are located

   > /Users/spoho/git/article
4. Which applications do you want to include in your configuration?

   > I selected the microservice and the gateway

After that the following error comes up:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'generator-jhipster' of undefined
at appsFolders.forEach (/Users/spoho/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/generator-jhipster/generators/docker-prompts.js:177:36)
at Array.forEach (native)
at prompt.then (/Users/spoho/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/generator-jhipster/generators/docker-prompts.js:174:26)
```

[docker-prompt.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Awy0t.png)
Any help appreciated.
Kindly 
Hendrik

Comment: There is not enough info to reproduce this. Can you provide the jhipster config you use and steps to reproduce

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same problem. For me, the solution was to add a backlash ( \ ) after you give the root directory to your applications. 
In your example, when you have to enter the root directory where your gateway(s) and microservices are located, you should enter the path like this: /Users/spoho/git/article/.The difference is that I added a slash at the end. Hope it works.